# How can we update or refresh/renew filtered array？-javascript

Tags: javascript

updating filtered array every time original array adds/inputs a new element

---

so every time I input a new element in the original array, then the filtered array gets refreshed and considers if the new element is in its condition

Answer (score 0):

What about this, i am overriding the push method of the original array, so that when an new element is added, another method is going to get called to refresh the filtered array:

```
var originalArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
var filteredArray = [...originalArray];
var filters = [];

// FUNCION THAT RECEIVES AN ARRAY AND OVERRIDES THE PUSH METHOD 
//SO THAT IT CAN EXECUTE A FUNCION AFTER PUSHING THE NEW ELEMENT
var AddEventToArrayPush = (arr, callback) => {
    arr.push = function(e) {
        Array.prototype.push.call(arr, e);
        callback(arr);
    };
};

var ResetFilters = () => {
    filters = [];
    filteredArray = [...originalArray];
}

var AddFilter = (filter) => {
    filters.push(filter);
}

var ApplyFilters = () => {
    filteredArray = [...originalArray];

    for (const filter of filters) {
        filteredArray = filteredArray.filter(filter);
    }
}

//CALLING THE FUNCTION TO OVERRIDE PUSH METHOD FOR THE ORIGINAL ARRAY
AddEventToArrayPush(originalArray, ApplyFilters)

// SOME FILTERS
const IS_EVEN_NUMBER = (number) => { return number % 2 == 0 };
const IS_GREATER_THEN_5 = (number) => { return number > 5 };

console.log("Initial filtered array:");
console.log(filteredArray.toString());

console.log("\r\nFiltering even numbers greater than 5");
AddFilter(IS_EVEN_NUMBER);
AddFilter(IS_GREATER_THEN_5);
ApplyFilters();

console.log("\r\nFiltered array after applying filters:");
console.log(filteredArray.toString());

originalArray.push(20);

console.log("\r\nFiltered array after pushing new element into original array:");
console.log(filteredArray.toString());
```